# How do I load the graph API for public pages

Tags: facebook, graph

I started a simple example trying to load Taylor Swift's public facebook page, and get the data with the graph API. I only seem to get an ID back in the result. How do I do this correctly, to get the data as advertised.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/

https://graph.facebook.com/TaylorSwift/?access_token=XXX

Unfortunately, How do I know if a page is public. Why do they hide all this information?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get an `access_token` to pull more data.

The `GET` endpoint for Facebook API `v2.4` is below:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/19614945368?access_token={your_token_here}
```

You can't know if a page is public, until you query it.

Facebook has changed their API. Before you could pull lots of public data. Not anymore.